# NoClassDefFoundError For IClass$DefaultImpls when writing default method for interface in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, classnotfoundexception, default-method

I have an interface `MyInterface` in Kotlin with some methods that some of them have a default implementation. Also, I have another interface `IClass` that extends `MyInterface` written in Java. At last, I have a class `MyClass` that implements `MyInteface` written in Kotlin. Now when I run my code, I got the following error.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myPackage.IClass$DefaultImpls
```

I test both Kotlin 1.2.51 and 1.3.0

When I write IClass in Kotlin, everything works as expected. 
What's wrong with my first code?

Comment: How are you compiling the code? Are you using Proguard?

Comment: No, I use Kotlin for my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to annotate your method with [JvmDefault](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-default/index.html) in Kotlin.  It's a new feature described in detail [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html#jvmdefault)

Comment: As of Kotlin 1.4, you can now set the `-Xjvm-default=all` compiler option. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#default-methods-in-interfaces and https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/07/kotlin-1-4-m3-generating-default-methods-in-interfaces/ for more details.

Answer (score 3):

This is [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12466) in the Kotlin compiler. As a workaround, please do use `@JvmDefault` as recommended in another answer.

Comment: As of Kotlin 1.4, you can now set the `-Xjvm-default=all` compiler option. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#default-methods-in-interfaces and https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/07/kotlin-1-4-m3-generating-default-methods-in-interfaces/ for more details.